# How to "frankenstine" wires?

Tags: usb, wire

How do I make a different usb wire type out of two different usb wires? For example, say I have two standard usb-to-micro-usb wires and I want to make one usb-to-usb and then one micro-usb-to-micro-usb. Could I just cut and strip both of the wires and then solder the two remaining usb heads together to make a usb-to-usb? (Same thing goes with the other micro USB heads)

With that, I can charge my device through my makeshift usb-to-usb connected to a female usb hub!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible in a pinch.

You will need make sure the pinouts correspond to the correct wires after you have cut the cable. They need to be matched with the other connector.

An example, here is a USB 2.0 pinout:

[image: USB 2.0 pinout]

You'll need to use a multimeter or ohmmeter to check for continuity of the wires and the pins and ensure they match with the correct pins on the other connector.

However, I would strongly advise against doing that; it's much less trouble (and more importantly, time) to just purchase your needed cables. The cables are also made to specific electrical specifications (e.g. current rating, resistance, etc.) that may or may not be to standard with a home made cable.

Comment: Soooo, do I have to connect the right threads inside to wire to the other threads ofmthe same type, or can I just jam it together and test it? Also, should I use this method to shorten the length of some wires?